# Why can't I modify a list passed as an argument inside a function?

Tags: python, list, scope, namespaces

Here is the context. I have a tree structure defined like this:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

and I am trying to recursively iterate over the tree with a function `find_x`. The function relies on a list `to_do` that is passed as an argument.

```
x = defaultdict(lambda:[])

def find_x (x, to_do):
    next_to_do = []

    for node, n in to_do:
        x[n].append(node.val)

        if node.left:
            next_to_do.append((node.left, n - 1))

        if node.right:
            next_to_do.append((node.right, n + 1))

    to_do = next_to_do

to_do = [(root, 0)]
while to_do:
    find_x(x, to_do)
```

When I run my function and I see that `to_do` is not updated. I understand that if I want `to_do` to be updated, I need to change `find_x` and replace the last line with `return next_to_do` and I need to change the inside of the `while` loop into `to_do = find_x(x, to_do)`.

My question is this. Since my list `to_do` is a mutable object and since it is defined outside of the function `find_x`, the function  `find_x` should be able to modify it. Why is it not not the case?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: it's because you are assigning the new array `next_to_do` to `to_do` that's why it's not changing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are creating a new variable `to_do` inside of your function  `find_x`, you may use:

```
to_do[:] = next_to_do
```